# Local time for drifted Brownian motion and comparison results for reflected diffusion

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X(t) = x+ \mu t + \sigma W(t)$ where $x\ge 0$, $\mu, \sigma>0$ are real constants, and $W$ is a standard Brownian motion. The Skorohod decomposition of $X(t)$ can be written as $Z(t) = X(t) + L_0(t),$ in which $Z(t)$ is a reflected diffusion and $L_0(t) $ is the local time process at the origin. My question is: what is $E[L_0(t)]$? I guess this is a simple question. But I don't see a solution right away.

Another question. Suppose we have two reflected diffusion processes: $$X_1(t) = x+ \int_0^t b_1(X_1(s))ds + \sigma W(t) + L_1(t), $$ and $$ X_2(t) = x+ \int_0^t b_2(X_2(s))ds + \sigma W(t) + L_2(t),$$ where $b_1(x) \le b_2(x)$ for all $x\ge 0$, and $L_1, L_2$ are the respective local time processes at the origin. Assume $b_1,b_2$ are Lipschitz continuous and satisfies the linear growth condition. Is there a comparison result similar to that of a diffusion process without reflection? So, I would like to know whether we have $X_1(t) \le X_2(t)$ and $L_1(t) \ge L_2(t) $ for all $t\ge 0$ with probability one? Thanks for your help.